# Get data from database using linq query and display it in dynamically generated labels in repeater

Tags: .net, linq

Client side:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="QuestionRepeater" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
   <ul>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <li><%# Eval("Question_Question") %></li>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </ul>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindRepeater();
    }
}

private void BindRepeater()
{
    var q = from u in db.tbl_Question select u.Question_Question;
    QuestionRepeater.DataSource = q.ToList();
    QuestionRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

Error:

Error is on line where use use `Eval("Question_Question")` function, i also tried `Bind("Question_Question")`.

> DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Question_Question'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Question_Question'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding the repeater to list of strings. Change the binder expression to:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Container.DataItem?.ToString() ?? string.Empty%>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: how could i get value of multiple textboxes genrated in ItemTemplate tag like this: <ItemTemplate>
<%# Container.DataItem?.ToString() ?? string.Empty%><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" TextMode="MultiLine"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>

Comment: Give them dynamic Ids and access them accordingly. e.g. TextBox1 is your ID.

Comment: How can i assign dynamic id to Textbox inside the repeater?

Comment: i get the the id of textbox and label dynamicly but i could not get id of div with runat server. please guide me how can i do this. i need to change the css of div created in repeater.